# How to re-fire click event in a fade callback?

Tags: jquery

Trying to do something rather simple here.. I have a click event set to few anchors, as portrayed in the code. Inside the click event function, I have fadeout with a callback function. I want to prevent anchor from firing until fadeout is complete, then re-fire it. This is what I gathered so far.. which doesn't work. I get the fade, then nothing happens.

```
$('#desktop_nav ul').find('a').click(function(e)
{       
    var that = this;
    //console.log(that);

    // prevent fade from firing on mid-click
    if (e.which != 2)
    {           
        e.preventDefault();

        $('html').fadeOut(2000, function(){
            //console.log(that);
            that.bind('click', function(){
                $(this).trigger('click');
                // returns "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Been looking through Stack for some answers, but looks like I lack some knowledge to fully understand those.

Thanks!

Comment: you are triggering click event on something that does not exist. what is that ?

Comment: I think you should try $(this).on('click',function(){//code here });

Comment: What do you mean? that = this. I had to do it, because 'this' inside the fadeout callback is scoped to 'html', thus not aiming the anchor that was clicked.

Comment: you can also try $(this).click(); it fire the click event with the code that I gave in last comment.

Comment: How will using .on help if I still need to prevent anchor from refreshing the page, fade, then re-fire it. Thanks for help, appreciated much.

Comment: What is THAT. i mean from that what is that you are trying to trigger click function on. it does not exist.

Comment: you can also try for example <a onclick="myFunction(event)>" and in your function myFunction(e) do you 2nd logic.

Comment: Oh.. well, I'm trying to trigger click over the initially clicked anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`that` refers to the raw DOM element (*since you set it with `var that = this`*)

You need to use `$(that).bind(...)`

---

The logic of binding a handler that when clicked will trigger a click on itself is flawed though, because it will create an infinite loop or triggering itself.

You need to just manually trigger the `click` when the fade completes

```
    $('html').fadeOut(2000, function(){
        //console.log(that);
        $(that).trigger('click');
    });
```

---

Try

```
    $('html').fadeOut(2000, function(){
        //console.log(that);
        window.location.href = that.href;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Did that. Still no joy. :\

Comment: @gay aka. why this inner trigger will not go into an infinite loop?

Comment: @asde you cannot trigger normal clicks through javascript. The `trigger('click')` will only fire jQuery handlers bound to the element.

Comment: @Meer because the function is called on the `fadeOut` completion. It has nothing to do with the clicked button (*which the `trigger` targers*)

Comment: So you're saying I must say bind before trigger, is that correct?

Comment: @asde nope. i am saying that if you want the normal click behaviour you will have to simulate it through javascript since you intercept it.

Comment: @meer it will. its the same thing. But the OP post does not call the click, he binds to it.

Comment: @asde updated answer to show simple simulation of the normal click behaviour. .

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this works beautifully!

```
$('#desktop_nav ul').find('a').click(function(e)
{
    var that = this;

    // prevent fade from firing on mid-click
    if (e.which != 2)
    {           
        e.preventDefault();

        $('html').fadeOut(2000, function(){
            window.location.href = that.href;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: is this same answer as given by gaby ?

Comment: Yes. I adjusted my initial code according to his suggestion. Now my website has nice, smooth fade between page transitions.

Comment: If his answer is the correct one. you can mark his answer as right. what do you think ?

Comment: Thanks, I just did. :)